# i am trying to show single data but it is showing" Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Tags: laravel

```
           **after clicking "read more" i want to show a single post**

               <a href="{{ URL::to('single/blog/'.$post->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary 
                    float-right">Read More &rarr;</a>

             ** **the route is****
               
      Route::get('single/blog/{id}','Web\Site\HomeController@show');

         **the controller is**
          public function show($id)
              {
               $posts = Post::findOrFail($id);
               return view('site.home.singleblog',compact('posts'));
                }

          ****the single section is****
```

- @foreach($posts as $post)
  <img class="img-responsive" src="{{asset("uploads/posts/$post->id/image/$post->image") }}" alt=""

  > 

{{ $post->name }} 
{{$post->description}}     
   @endforeach

---

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `$posts` is a single Post instance from `Post::findOrFail($id)` (where `$id` is coming from a route parameter, so a single value). You don't want to be iterating an instance of a Model. Use it in your view like a single model instance not a collection.

```
public function show($id)
{
    view('site.home.singleblog', [
        'post' => Post::findOrFail($id),
    ]);
}
```

Then in the view just remove the `@foreach` and `@endforeach`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
{{ $post['name'] }} {{$post['description']}}
```

If you fetched $posts successfully, it should work. The error says $post is not an object but you are using object syntax to get value by key. So use array syntax.

Comment: thank you . but it is still showing error  "Undefined index: name"

Comment: As I said in my answer, it should work if you fetched $posts. So $posts should be empty, in this case. If you want to get proper support, format your code properly. Your code is unreadable unless I decide to spend my time.